spring jdbctemplate not returning stored procedure with implicit cursor
i have a SP like the following
create or replace mystoredprocedure(userid VARCHAR, batchno VARCHAR) as 
begin
 open cursor c1 for 
    select * from table A;
 dbms_sql.return_result(c1);
open cursor c2 for 
    select * from table B;
 dbms_sql.return_result(c2);
end;

Using 1 -
This is throwing "cannot perform fetch on a pl/sql statement : next
1. jdbctemplate. query ("call mystoredprocedure", new Object[]{userid,batchno}, new int[]{Types.VARCHAR,Types.VARCHAR},new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(SampleBO.class));

Using 2 -This isnt giving result
2. 
MyStoredProcedure extends StoredProcedure
MyStoredProcedure mysp = new MyStoredProcedure(jdbcTemplate,"mystoredprocedure");
mysp.compile();
mysp.setParameters( sqlParameter array);
Map result = mysp.execute(param1,param2)

Using 3 - The results size is blank
3. SimpleJdbcCall jdbccall  =  new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbctemplate).withProcedureName("mystoredprocedure").withoutprocedurecolumnmetadataaccess().withnamebinding().returningresultset("rs1,new BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(MyBean1.class)).returningresultset("rs2,new BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(MyBean2.class).addDeclaredParameter(new SqlParameter("userid",Types.VARCHAR)).addDeclaredParameter(new SqlParameter("batchno",Types.VARCHAR));

Map actualParams = new HashMap();
actualParams.add("userid","20025");
actualParams.add("batchno","BATCH20025");

Map<String,object> results = jdbccall.execute(actualParams);

Any other way to fetch the two resultsets?
Please help

As far as I remember, there is a problem with Oracle returning ORA-17283 on the second result set making the caller believe there is no more cursor returned and that the solution was to call stmt.getMoreResults() on that specific error, and then retry getResultSet(). However if this was easy to implement in JDBC, probably you will have to sub-class some from Spring if you don't want to switch to JDBC for that call.
Here an example of solution for anonymous block:
public interface ResultSetProcessor {
    void process(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException;

    void notifyResultSetChange();
}

/**
 * When using ORACLE 12c feature to return the cursor: DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(cur)
 * 
 * @param sqlConn
 * @param sqlBlock
 * @param processor
 * @throws SQLException
 */

public static void anonymousBlockCursorOra12(final Connection sqlConn, final String sqlBlock,
        final ResultSetProcessor processor) throws SQLException {
    try (final PreparedStatement s = sqlConn.prepareStatement(sqlBlock)) {
        boolean result = s.execute();

        do {
            // Check for more results if not already done in this iteration
            if (result) {
                try (final ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet()) {
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        processor.process(rs);
                    }
                }
                catch (final SQLException e) {
                    // Ignore ORA-17283: No resultset available
                    if (e.getErrorCode() != 17283) {
                        LOGGER.error(UtilsOJDBCLogPrefix.SQL_EXCEPTION, e);
                        throw e;
                    }
                }
                result = s.getMoreResults();
                if (result) {
                    processor.notifyResultSetChange();
                }
            }
            else if (s.getUpdateCount() == -1) {
                // Ignore -1 value if there is one more result!
                result = s.getMoreResults();
            }
        }
        while (result);
    }
}

